# change AutoCompleteTextView underline color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm having some trouble changing the color of an AutoCompleteTextView's underline, through styles.

We're using appcompat-v7, minimum SDK version is 16 and target and compiled are 21.

This is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_chooser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Autocomplete"
        android:hint="@string/chooseShop"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is how I include it in other layouts:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_inc"
        layout="@layout/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is my Autocomplete style:

```
<style name="Autocomplete" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#d9fafafa</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#80bdbdbd</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_autocomplete</item>
    </style>
```

And this the background's 9 patch image:

[image: 9patch]

My problem is that the AutoCompleteTextView gets positioned way lower than it should:

[image: not_working]

This is how the app looks if I remove the 'background' attribute from my custom style:

[image]

I know that this can be achieved on api 21 using 'accentColor', but I'm talking about pre-21 here.

I want just to change the line's color, any suggestion or alterative solution is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with you 9.patch image .. It has way too much space on the top of it.

Either edit it yourself or ask your graphics designer to shave off some space from top.